# Cannot Read properties of undefined React. Log only works on object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently trying to create a weather website using weatherapi, but I'm running into a problem. If I log the object of location there's no error, but if I try to log anything deeper than that object, like the name of the city it cannot read properties of undefined. If I comment out the log when it's using the name of the city, then uncomment it again and don't reload the page, then it will log the name of the city without error.

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar"
import {useState} from "react"
import Weather from './components/Weather';


function App() {
  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState({})
  const [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState([])
  const [loc, setLoc] = useState({loc:"Arlington"})
  let apiKey = "xxxxxxxx"
  // console.log("Location: "+ loc.loc)

  React.useEffect(() =>{///Finds weather data of certain location
    console.log(loc.loc)
    fetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${apiKey}&q=${loc.loc}&aqi=no`)
    .then(res => {
      if(res.ok){
        return res.json()
      }
    })

    .then(data => {
      if(data !=null){//Only change currentWeather when there is data for it
        setCurrentWeather(data)
      }else{
        alert(`${loc.loc} was not found`)
      }
    })
  }, [loc])

  React.useEffect(() =>{///Finds locations with search bar
    fetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/search.json?key=${apiKey}&q=${loc.loc}&aqi=no`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      if(data.loc == null){
      }else{
        setLoc(data)
      }
    })
  }, [])

  
  //console.log(currentWeather.location.name)
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar inputData={inputData} setLoc={setLoc} setInputData={setInputData}/>
      <Weather currentWeather={currentWeather}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues I see:

1. You are initializing `currentWeather` to an array, but it should probably be either `undefined` or an object (`{}`) based on your use of it. To fix this, use one of these:

```js
const [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState()
// or
const [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState({})
```

2. You are trying to access `currentWeather.location.name` before you have updated `currentWeather` to have those properties. That's why you're getting that error.

The best solution for this is to use optional chaining https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

So try this:

```js
console.log(currentWeather?.location?.name)
```

3. Your `console.log` is just in the body of the function component, meaning it will only be called once (with the initial value), I think. To fix this, and log every time the value of `currentWeather` changes, you can do this instead:

```js
React.useEffect(() => { console.log(currentWeather?.location?.name) }, [currentWeather])
```

Comment: Today I learned about optional chaining. Awesome. That worked and the first was just a typo.